# How to plot before a new bar open/future bar/forecast line

Tags: pine-script

I have a simple rate of change code and would like to see its level/reading as soon as the current bar is closed. How can I modify the code to plot this future/forecast line?

```
ROC2 = close[1] - close[3] + close[2]
plot(ROC2)
```

[uploaded image of the expected outcome with manually drew extended red line under "ROC2" pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33hW7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `barstate.isconfirmed` to draw on the last update of the bar. And then use `line.new` to draw your line into future.

In the below example, the white line is an extension of your plot based on the last two values. The red line will just extend the latest value.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

ROC2 = close[1] - close[3] + close[2]

plot(ROC2)

if (barstate.isconfirmed)
    l1 = line.new(bar_index - 1, ROC2[1], bar_index, ROC2, color=color.white, style=line.style_dashed, extend=extend.right)
    l2 = line.new(bar_index, ROC2, bar_index + 1, ROC2, color=color.red, style=line.style_dashed, extend=extend.right)
    line.delete(l1[1])
    line.delete(l2[1])
```

[image]

Please note that `AMZN` is in post market here.

Comment: thanks for the help Vitruvius, however the both lines doesnt reflect the expected outcome. I've edited the post with an uploaded image, ideally the script will "pre-plot" today ROC2 (which is $166.79 for AMZN) on the chart, before the market open. 
Is it possible to achieve such "pre-plot" or forecast function?

Comment: How do you calculate $166.79?

Comment: from the ROC2 calculation, which is 167.08-169.8+169.51